# Regex pattern not working in MySQL when I try to deny the dot

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to use a regex in MySQL. I have this expresión `[a-zA-Z]^\\.` I supossed the `^` symbol will deny the dot in the expression. If I write a text string with a dot I receive 0 matches but when I write a text string without the dot I also receive 0 matches. For example:

```
SELECT  'roger' REGEXP  '[a-zA-Z]^\\.'
```

gives me 0 matches. I just need to verify if this expresión ^ denies the dot or not and what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you're trying to match?

Comment: Without anchors or something else, Barmar's Answer will match `AB.` .  You need to tighten up the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` only means to exclude characters when it's at the beginning of a `[...]` character set. Outside that, it matches the beginning of the string.

If you want to match a non-dot, you should use `[^.]`.

```
SELECT 'roger' REGEXP '[a-zA-Z][^.]'
```

But since this will match anywhere in the string, it won't work for excluding strings that contain `.`. Instead you should reverse the condition:

```
SELECT 'roger.' NOT REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]\\.'
```

Comment: Sorry I thought that worked because it matches 1 for the string without the dot, but it also  matches 1 for a string with a dot. Like this SELECT 'roger.' REGEXP '[a-zA-Z][^.]' so this solution does not deny the dot either

Comment: It matches anywhere in the string. So it matches `ro` because `[a-zA-Z]` matches `r` and `[^.]` matches `o`.

Comment: I've updated the answer: you should use `NOT REGEXP` to exlude that.

Comment: Thanks Barman. Your solution works fine and I did not know one can use not regexp, it is a good option. But I am still a little confused because I thought that using the ^ symbol inside an expression would exclude anything after it.

Comment: `^` has two meanings in regexp. At the beginning of `[...]` it means to exclude. Outside `[...]` it means to match the beginning of the string.